# write array to file after looping node js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have yet to find a answer to my problem with the examples from questions others have asked on this. 
I wrote a little web scraper that stores data to 1 array and would like to write it (the arrays) to a file. I'm having trouble setting things up correctly.

I am using nodejs. Could someone write a sample that takes an array content then writes to a file. please break it down to basic, I am still new at programming.

Thanks the code is below

```
var content = [];
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var URL = 'http://www.amazon.com';



 request(URL, function(error, response, html){

   if (error){

       consol.log('Error:', error);
   }
   if (response.statusCode !== 200) {

       console.log('Invalid Status Code Returned:', response.statusCode);
   }

   //console.log(html);
      var $ = cheerio.load(html);


    $('td').each(function (i, element) {


        var a = $(this).next();
        var trimmed_a = a.text();

        trimmed_a = trimmed_a.trim();
        var str = trimmed_a.replace(/\s\s+/g,"");
        var newStr = str.trim();

        content.push(newStr);



    });

    console.log(content);
```

})

Comment: You need to show us what is in the arrays.  Is it just strings?  Objects with properties?  Numbers?  And, you have to describe what format you want the file to be in?  Show us a sample of the data in your array format and show us what you want the format in the file to be.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes.... it is the values taken of the sites

Comment: What does your array look like, if it's just simple types like string numbers, etc.. You could JSON.stringify, and then save this to disk.

Comment: @keith I edited my post..please run the code

Comment: Looks like you just pushing strings into a an array, that will serialize with JSON.stringify without issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest possible answer:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var arr = ['cat','dog','bird'];
var filename = 'output.txt';
var str = JSON.stringify(arr, null, 4);

fs.writeFile(filename, str, function(err){
    if(err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log('File written!');
    }
});
```

Here, `arr`, would be your array of data, that your casting to a string because `fs.writeFile` [expects a string](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback). I used the `null,4` additional arguments to make it pretty print so you can see it with a four space indent.

Hope this helps!

Comment: the array is larger than 3 items. I edited my post please see above.

Comment: That's fine, JSON.stringify will handle thousands of items,.

Comment: @Nb_me - This code works no matter how large the array is.  It just writes out the whole array.

Comment: you can use any array, just put `content` where I have `arr` in the stringify function.

Comment: @jfriend00 this works but there are gaps I have to gain a better understanding so I can arrange things better.

Comment: `this works but there are gap`  What do you mean there are Gaps?, if you mean there are spaces in the JSON string, that was deliberately done by Jason, he mentions that `null,4`,  for serialising purposes you don't need it.  btw. To read this back use the reverse  JSON.parse(str);

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to store a real array/object in a file – its contents are bytes, however you can store a stringified format of this object, then parse this same format, using JSON for example (I think this [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) equivals to Node.js):

```
json_format = JSON.stringify(content)
var json_format
```

So, if you want to read the array in the file after getting its contents

```
JSON.parse(json_format)
```

Remind, in JSON there is no kind of function declarations, all primitive values are supported, except `NaN`, `Infinity`, `undefined` (that is not a value), etc., and still include special number syntaxes (exponent (+ | -), ...): [JSON](http://json.org). All values that JSON doesn't support, `JSON.stringify` treats them as `null`. I'm not sure how it exactly works between different platforms, though (I only use browser JS).

Now, to save/write the file we currently have 
asynchronous [fs.writeFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) and synchronous [fs.writeFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options). I don't know much about Node.js, though. When using these methods you must include the File System in somewhere, normally so (File System is in a module):

```
fs = require('fs'); var fs
```

Comment: Thank you for the initial paragraph of explanation. Really cleared away my confusion!